# Event system: callbacks or event queue

Tags: c++, event-handling, game-engine

I am currently developing an event system for my game engine. I've thought of two ways to implement the event handling:

**1. An "event queue"**

```
std::queue<Event*> events;
// ...

while(hasUnhandledEvents())
{
    Event e = pollEvent();

    // ... handle event
}
```

**2. Callback functions**

```
void cbfun(const Event &e)
{
    // ... handle event
}

// ...

setCallbackFunction(cbfun);
```

I'm not quite sure which system suits best. I would have rather chosen the callback function, but the problem I have with them is when the callback function is part of a class. I don't know exactly why but it's very tedious to pass the function pointer... I know I can use an std::function, but this seems a little bit unelegant to me (because of the placeholders etc...). Should I still use the callback function or consider the event queue? What do you prefer?

Comment: Apart from maintaining a list of polymorphic objects, a vector of pointers is rarely needed.

Comment: @Ron An Event class in a game engine would be polymorphic almost with certainty.

Comment: Ignoring the actual question for a moment, if you go for option 1 you want a queue, not a stack. Using a stack would reverse the order of events.